# switch case js two parameters

Tags: javascript, parameters, switch-statement, case

Please tell me how I can do with two parameters and simplify this code to a normal state. Thank you! This logic is very necessary for me, I hope for your indulgence.

```
var treshhold_two = 0;

function Test(attack, ratio) {
  switch (attack) {
    case 0,01:
      switch (ratio) {
        case 2:
          treshhold = 2798,6;
          break;
        case 4:
          treshhold = 3678,16;
          break;
        case 6:
          treshhold = 5757,12;
          break;
      }
      break;
    case >0,01:
      switch (attack, ratio) {
        case 0,03,2:
          treshhold = -5,75712;
          break;
        case 0,03,4:
          treshhold = -5,75712 * 1,1;
          break; // -45%
        case 0,03,6:
          treshhold = -5,75712 * 0,96;
          break; // -52%, and etc.
        ...
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `if` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var treshhold_two = 0;

function Test(attack, ratio) {
  if(attack == 0,01) {
     switch (ratio) {
        case 2:
          treshhold = 2798,6;
          break;
        case 4:
          treshhold = 3678,16;
          break;
        case 6:
          treshhold = 5757,12;
          break;
       }
   }
   else {           
      switch (attack) {
        case 0,03:
              if(ratio==2) treshhold = -5,75712;                 
              if(ratio==4) treshhold = -5,75712 * 1,1;                             
              if(ratio==6) treshhold = -5,75712 * 0,96;                  
              break;
        ...
      }          
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    //option:1

    var treshhold = 0;

    function Test(attack, ratio) {
      switch (attack) {
        case 0,01:
                if(ratio==2) treshhold = 2798,6;               
          if(ratio==4) treshhold = 3678,16;                          
          if(ratio==6) treshhold = 5757,12;
            break;
        case 0,03:
          if(ratio==2) treshhold = -5,75712;             
          if(ratio==4) treshhold = -5,75712 * 1,1;                         
          if(ratio==6) treshhold = -5,75712 * 0,96;
          break;
          // ...
          }
      }
    }


    //option:2

    var treshhold = 0;

    function Test(attack, ratio) {
      switch (attack) {
        case 0,01:
            switch (ratio) {
            case 2: treshhold = 2798,6; break;
            case 4: treshhold = 3678,16; break;
            case 6: treshhold = 5757,12; break;
          }
        case 0,03:
            switch (ratio) {
            case 2: treshhold = -5,75712;  break;
            case 4: treshhold = -5,75712 * 1,1; break;
            case 6: treshhold = -5,75712 * 0,96;; break;
          }
         // ...
          }
     }
```

//option:3

```
var treshhold = 1223456;

function Test(ratio, attack) {
  switch (ratio) {
    case 2:
        switch (attack) {
        case 0,01: ... break;
        case 0,03: ... break;
        case 0,1: ... break;
      }
      break;
    case 4:
        switch (attack) {
        case 0,01: ... break;
        case 0,03: ... break;
        case 0,1: ... break;
      }
      break;
    case 6:
        switch (attack) {
        case 0,01: ... break;
        case 0,03: ... break;
        case 0,1: ... break;
      }
      break;
 }


// option?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var treshhold_two = 0;

function Test(attack, ratio) {
  if (attack == 0.01) {
      switch (ratio) {
        case 2:
          treshhold = 2798.6;
          break;
        case 4:
          treshhold = 3678.16;
          break;
        case 6:
          treshhold = 5757.12;
          break;
      }
    }
    else if (attack > 0.01) {
      switch (attack, ratio) {
        case 0,03,2: // what does it mean ?
          treshhold = -5.75712;
          break;
        case 0,03,4: // what does it mean ?
          treshhold = -5.75712 * 1.1;
          break; // -45%
        case 0,03,6: // what does it mean ?
          treshhold = -5.75712 * 0.96;
          break; // -52%, and etc.
        ...
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this should work as a cycle that is continuously, because the user can switch between the settings. case 0,03,2: // 0.03 - attcack, 2 - ratio